# How to get the property value in Laravel Blade that was transformed by Eloquent API Resource?

Tags: laravel

Currently, my solution to display an encoded ID is like that:

```
<p v-text='"Reservation code: "+ @json($orderJson).id'></p> //R. code: wYeyjo6l42
```

But I would prefer to use it like:

```
<p>@json($orderJson->id)</p> //but returns: 8 (not encoded)
```

How can I get the transformed attributes?

p.S. Yes I know it's used for API, but I'm even using it to handle objects to Vue via Blade.

Comment: another solution would be even {{ json_decode(json_encode($orderJson))->id }}. But it's gross...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I dug up in the code and found out you can use resolve().

So one solution would be:

```
<p>Reservation code: {{ $orderJson->resolve()['id'] }}</p>
```